# Marginal Distribution: Integrate a variable out

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have given the joint density $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$ of two random variables $X, Y$, where $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=g(x,y) \mathbb{1}_{y > t}$.

Now we want to compute the marginal density of $X$, hence we integrate over $Y$.

In my lecture notes we have the following integral:

$$f_X(x)= \int_t^{\infty} g(x,y) dy,$$

but doesn't it matter whether we go from $t$ including $t$ or not including $t$? I am not sure about this because I haven't attended a lecture about measure and integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn about measures or integrals.

Assuming $g(x,y)$ is well behaved (e.g. finite), the difference the integrals including or excluding $t$ is $0$.

Your intuition might see this as rather like measuring the length of a line segment including or excluding its endpoints: the difference in lengths is infinitesimal or zero.

Comment: Yes, I know that I need to learn about measures or integrals. But as a computer scientist trying to learn about stochastic processes I have quite a hard time learning all these things on my own when only having had one introductory course on basic probability and one small very applied course about analysis. So please be patient. Do you know a good book, ... where the most important things are explained?

But anyway: Thank you very much for your answer. This makes a lot of sense and this is how I usually would understand integrals, but I was confused because of the Lebesgue integrals,...

Comment: @user136457 If you are using a textbook for probability theory, look to the appendices-- these types of books will usually have a primer on Lebesgue integration.

Answer (score 1):

Integrals can be useful for many different applications. Once you understand the concept for any application, the idea of inclusion or exclusion is just an extension of that. Say in financial mathematics you have an interest rate payable continuously, you would use an integral to account for all the payments made at each point in time as the points in time over that interval tend to infinity. If you are working out areas of solids, you would work out the area as an integral over a certain interval (as if you were adding the areas at each point on that interval as the number of points tends to infinity).

Say this interval is (a,b) so a and b are not excluded. It does not really matter because the first point will be so close to a that it is practically the same thing. The interval over (a,b) = the interval over [a,b]